# Mutating an int inside a constexpr function

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

Why can I do this:

```
constexpr auto i_can() {
   int a = 8;
   a = 9;
   //...
}
```

But I cannot do this:

```
constexpr auto i_cannot() {
    std::array<int, 10> arr{};
    //I cannot
    arr[5] = 9;
}
```

My questions are:

1. If I can mutate an `int`, why can I not mutate an `int` that is inside the array?
2. Is this a language limitation (C++14) or a standard library spec problem? `reference std::array<T, N>::operator[](size_t)` is not currently `constexpr`.

Comment: Related: [LWG issue 2243](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-active.html#2443)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is a limitation of the standard library since you **can** modify a plain C array in a `constexpr`:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr auto demo()
{
   int arr[10] = {};
   arr[5] = 9;
   return arr[5];
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(demo() == 9, "");
    std::cout << demo() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Cu8CSW9MNL0k7CMg)

**output**

```
9
```

If you added `constexpr` to `operator[]` of an implementation of `array`, you could also use this operator inside a  `constexpr`.

[DEMO](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Lc9Hs7HrsQoOMHXs)

Comment: Is this a guess or an answer?

Comment: Your code does not prove that `demo` is producing a constant expression when called. You'd have to write e.g. `static_assert(demo() == 9, "");` to be sure.

Comment: @Columbo thanks for the hint, I added the `static_assert`

Comment: @ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ I guess this is an answer :)

Comment: @m.s. How do you know that?

Answer (score 17):

Modification of objects inside `constexpr` functions has been introduced with C++14. However, while modifying e.g. a scalar by an assignment is fine, modifying a class object through a member function still needs that member function to be `constexpr`. And unfortunately, as you mentioned, the current `std::array` specification does not declare the non-`const` `operator[]` as `constexpr`.
Hence, §7.1.5/5 makes your definition ill-formed:

> For a non-template, non-defaulted `constexpr` function […], if no
>   argument values exist such that an invocation of the function […]
>   could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression
>   (5.20), […], the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

You can temporarily use a more modern implementation if you want full `constexpr`-ness. E.g. [`Constainer::Array`](https://github.com/Arcoth/Constainer/blob/master/Array.hxx).

Comment: so it happens the same with bitset :(

Comment: @GermánDiago Well, use [`Constainer::Bitset`](https://github.com/Arcoth/Constainer/blob/master/Bitset.hxx) :-P

Comment: Just an observation, "constainer" is actually the name of the library Columbo refers to, and not a misspelling.